# Access VBA Return form control value from variable

Tags: vba, variables, ms-access-2013

I am trying to return the value of a form control using the below coding, unfortunately i get the error "Runtime error 2465, Cant find the field "Forms!Frm1!Control1 referred to in your expression".

```
vartest = "Forms!" & Screen.ActiveForm.Name & "!Control1"
MsgBox Controls(vartest).Value
```

Please can someone help so I can get the value to be returned?
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of form is this? Do you have userforum or what is this?

Comment: Hi,Apologies this is an MS Access 2013 single form.

Comment: Is the form visible (and not in design mode) when you're running this code?

Comment: The form is visible and not in design mode when i run the code. Thanks.